# Audio recording software that allows setting markers?

Tags: audio-recording, audio-editing

While recording a podcast, it would be useful to be able to set markers for later editing. Eg, to mark that I just heard...

- a mistake or awkward silence that I want to edit out
- a bit of info that should go in the show notes
- a great soundbite for previewing the episode

*Ideally* I could define some marker types and keyboard shortcuts - eg `mm` for "mark mistake", to be shown as a red marker, `mi` for for "mark info", to be shown as a green marker, etc.

However, any kind of "mark for later review" feature would be better than trying to scribble down "5:38" somewhere myself.

I'm currently using Audacity and don't see a way to do this.

So I'm looking for:

- Audio recording software that allows setting markers while recording to help guide later editing
- Preferably available for MacOS
- Paid is OK. I'd like to know about any options, regardless of price, although obviously cheap or free is nice if possible.

Does any audio recording / editing software include a feature like this?

Comment: I think Audacity will actually allow you to set a marker.  They call them labels though...  Quick over view - https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-insert-a-marker-in-audacity   More pics/details - http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Track-Markers-in-Audacity

Answer (score 2):

While playing back audio in Audacity, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> on Mac) to insert a label at the current playback position.

You can type a note while playback continues if you wish, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the note.  Or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> at any time to finish the current note and start a new one at the new playback point.

To add a label while editing, rather than playing, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> on Mac) will insert a note at the current cursor position, or spanning the current selection.  Or just click on the appropriate point in the Labels track and start typing.

You can edit a note by clicking its label.  You can delete an empty note by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> while editing it.

Labels can be exported or imported in text format from the File menu.

Answer (score 1):

[Total Recorder Pro](http://www.totalrecorder.com/productfr_trpro.htm) may meet your requirements, although it appears for Windows machines only. Here's one segment of the description to meet your requirement for markers:

> Use Cue-sheet files. Total Recorder lets you create cue-points, which can be used for splitting a file afterwards. These cue-points can be created manually, for example to make a bookmark in a sound file. Or they can be created automatically during a recording session (based on pause reduction, changes of the clip information in an external player, etc.) or while capturing streaming audio and information about a track changes.

At a price of just shy of US$36.00, it won't break the bank, if non-Mac doesn't break the deal.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Logic Pro X](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13187?locale=es_MX), Its exelent software for recording an editing for Mac Os, another software could be [Ardour](https://ardour.org) that is more dificult but so professional too.